# wikimapia api isn't working anymore

Tags: android, wikimapia

I'm using the wikimapia api for developing an Android application. I've used my first key for about two months but not, for any request I make I get:

```
{
    "debug": {
        "code": 1004,
        "message": "Key limit has been reached"
    }
}
```

I've created a new key, but now, for any request I make I get the same response: []

Does anybody know what the problem is?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like something wrong on Wikimapi side. It returns me `[]` too.

There are few post about this issue on wikimapia forum
http://wikimapia.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=4&t=14933&p=288045&hilit=empty#p288045

Comment: Yes, one of the posts are from me, unfortunately there's still no response regarding the problem (what's the cause or if it's going to be solved soon)